Monitor on usb-c automatically reduced resolution
My current setup is using an HP Omen laptop (full specs below) which has a USB-C port and an HDMI port. For years I have been running two monitors on 2560x1440 resolution by plugging one monitor straight into the HDMI port and the other using a USB-HDMI adapter.
The laptop fell to the floor recently and since the fall the USB socket has started playing up. I'd move the USB-c cable around to get the monitor working. Once working if you don't move the cable everything works fine at high resolution. But if the cable moves slightly you either lose the monitor fully (saying no HDMI signal received) or the monitor degrades to 1920x1080.
I am wondering whats causing this degraded 1080p resolution? Could it be due to some pins being damaged or a damaged USB board? Does a hardware damage result in degraded resolution or could there be an OS/driver thing that could help fix this?
Any helpful ideas? (other than replacing hardware :p)
Hardware specs

Omen by HP Laptop
Processor: Intel i5 4 cores
Display Adapter: Intel UHD Graphics 630
Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050

Windows 11 Home

It could well be damaged pins in the USB socket. Higher resolutions need higher bandwidths and may well need more of the USB 3 signal pairs to achieve that higher bandwidth. Take it to somewhere you can get the socket repaired.
